# can't connect to kafka container in the local network

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am running a zookeeper and kafka instance from the docker yaml file in my ubuntu 18.04

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test-topic:5:2"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

it is working as

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                NAMES
d3d84a6b39f7   wurstmeister/kafka          "start-kafka.sh"         3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:49157->9092/tcp                              desktop_kafka_1
b2012f08b3f9   wurstmeister/zookeeper      "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   5 hours ago     Up 3 minutes   22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   desktop_zookeeper_1
```

however the kafka client failed to connect the kafka as

```
const { Kafka,logLevel,CompressionCodecs,CompressionTypes } = require('kafkajs');
const kafka = new Kafka({
  logLevel: logLevel.DEBUG,
  brokers: ['localhost:9092'],   // tried on ['192.168.1.6:9092']
  clientId: 'example-producer',
})

const topic = 'topic-test'
const producer = kafka.producer()

const getRandomNumber = () => Math.round(Math.random(10) * 1000)
const createMessage = num => ({
  key: `key-${num}`,
  value: `value-${num}-${new Date().toISOString()}`,
})

const sendMessage = () => {
  return producer
    .send({
      topic,
      compression: CompressionTypes.GZIP,
      messages: Array(getRandomNumber())
        .fill()
        .map(_ => createMessage(getRandomNumber())),
    })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(e => console.error(`[example/producer] ${e.message}`, e))
}

const run = async () => {
  await producer.connect()
  setInterval(sendMessage, 3000)
}

run().catch(e => console.error(`[example/producer] ${e.message}`, e))
```

the code outputs

```
    [example/producer] Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9092 KafkaJSNonRetriableError
  Caused by: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9092
    at Socket.onError (/home/xsz/Desktop/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:152:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  name: 'KafkaJSNumberOfRetriesExceeded',
  retriable: false,
  helpUrl: undefined,
  originalError: KafkaJSConnectionError: Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9092
      at Socket.onError (/home/xsz/Desktop/node_modules/kafkajs/src/network/connection.js:152:23)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    retriable: true,
    helpUrl: undefined,
    broker: 'localhost:9092',
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
  },
  retryCount: 5,
  retryTime: 10304
}
```

In the docker-compose.ymal,  the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME is configured as localhost or 192.168.1.6 (host machine 's local ip address), both show the same error as above.

note:
using the

> ip addr show command outputs

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo

3: wlx08570033e6c1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 
   inet 192.168.1.6/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute wlx08570033e6c1

4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0

5: br-c66cb3672872: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-c66cb3672872

22: br-521b1eb41768: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-521b1eb41768
```

latest try:

I made a modification on the docker-compose.yaml

```
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 172.17.0.1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

and running the code on the host machine.

```
const kafka = new Kafka({
  logLevel: logLevel.DEBUG,
  brokers: ['172.17.0.1:9092'],   // tried on ['192.168.1.6:9092']
  clientId: 'example-producer',
})
```

but still facing the same issue, what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes need to be made

first, change connection host to `localhost`

```
const kafka = new Kafka({
    logLevel: logLevel.DEBUG,
    brokers: ['localhost:9092'],  
    clientId: 'example-producer',
})
```

then inside docker-compose file
change `ports` and  add `links`

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    links:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test-topic:5:2"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

last you only use one broker at your compose-file

I look at your configuration using Kafka-tool2.0 it seems that there is only one partition for "topic-test" that's why you see this error use more brokers to avoid this

```
 {"level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2020-12-15T07:54:05.315Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Request Metadata(key: 3, version: 6)","broker":"localhost:9092","clientId":"example-producer","correlationId":25,"expectResponse":true,"size":47}There is no listener on the leader broker that matches the listener on which metadata request was processed KafkaJSNonRetriableError Caused by: KafkaJSProtocolError: There is no listener on the leader broker that matches the listener on which metadata request was processed.
```

Tasted on Linux mint 20

output:

```
{"level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2020-12-15T06:55:59.662Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Produce(key: 0, version: 7)","broker":"localhost:9092","clientId":"example-producer","correlationId":46,"size":58,"data":{"topics":[{"topicName":"topic-test","partitions":[{"partition":0,"errorCode":0,"baseOffset":"18379","logAppendTime":"-1","logStartOffset":"0"}]}],"throttleTime":0,"clientSideThrottleTime":0}}
[
  {
    topicName: 'topic-test',
    partition: 0,
    errorCode: 0,
    baseOffset: '18379',
    logAppendTime: '-1',
    logStartOffset: '0'
  }
]
```

Comment: it seems the kafka is connected but getting anther issue saying   
    {"level":"DEBUG","timestamp":"2020-12-15T07:54:05.315Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Request Metadata(key: 3, version: 6)","broker":"localhost:9092","clientId":"example-producer","correlationId":25,"expectResponse":true,"size":47}There is no listener on the leader broker that matches the listener on which metadata request was processed KafkaJSNonRetriableError
  Caused by: KafkaJSProtocolError: There is no listener on the leader broker that matches the listener on which metadata request was processed.

Comment: i look at your configuration using Kafka-tool2.0 it seem that there is only one partition for "topic-test" that's way you see this error

Comment: I see, you mean test-topic:5:2, it is 5 partitions and 2 replia. if I need to make 5 partitions then I need to build a kafka cluster with 5 kafka instances, isn't it

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mapped the port of your kafka instance correctly in you docker compose file you should change

```
ports:
  - "9092"
```

with

```
ports:
  - "9092:9092"
```

as now you container gets assigned with an arbitrary port
`0.0.0.0:49157->9092/tcp`